# How to call variable outside function?

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to call a variable I have set to get the total time elasped for said function but for some reason it won't let me use it outside or it gives me the wrong output. Any ideas on what is wrong

```
recur_fib()
{
  first_num=$1
  start=$SECONDS
  [ $first_num -lt 2 ]  && echo -n $first_num || echo -n $(( $( recur_fib $(( first_num - 1 )) ) + $( recur_fib $(( first_num - 2 )) ) ))
  elapsedtime=$(($SECONDS - $start))
}

total_time_recur=$(recur_fib $elapsedtime)
val=$(recur_fib $1)
```

Where I'm trying to call it

```
case $method in
        "N" | "n")
                echo "You chose non-recursive";;
        "R" | "r")
                #repeat the the method and number chosen
                echo -e "RECURSIVE $1\n"

                echo -e "Run\tFibonacci\tTime"

                count=1
                while [ $count -le $1 ]
                do
                        echo -e "$count" '\t' $val '\t'  $total_time_recur
                        ((count = count + 1))
                done

                ;;
        *)
                echo "Please chose either R,r or N,n"

esac
```

Comment: As an aside, note that `echo -e` is unreliable. Even if your shell is 100% certain to be bash, in some compile-time or runtime configurations it can print the string `-e` on output; safer to use `printf`, as [the POSIX `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) recommends. (See also Stephane's excellent answer to the [unix.se] question [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo))

Comment: Anyhow, as for the issue -- you're creating a command substitution. Those run in subshells. Subshells are separate processes, so variables set within them aren't visible to the parent process.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response charles I will read up on the printf vs echo -e. I thought when calling variables outside the function you needed to put their function theyre related with? Did I just format it wrong?

Comment: ...that said, it would be much more helpful if you showed us your actual output, and described _why_ that output was wrong and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: So, a variable can be set by a function and then accessed outside it, but only if you call the function in the same shell. `$( )` creates a new `fork()`ed-off child process; it's not the same shell.

Comment: I am getting the error first that say's "line 17: [: -lt: unary operator expected". As for the output I am getting -3 in my time column which is not right.

Comment: Notice how you're using `elapsedtime` in one place and `elapsed_time` in another?

Comment: ...the other thing is that `$1` in the outermost copy of `recur_fib` doesn't get updated when `elapsed_time` (or `elapsedtime`) changes.

Comment: ...and please do [edit] the question so the actual error is part of its text and not just in the comments.

Comment: BTW, I don't see why `-3` is so obviously wrong (as output for this code, I mean; it's obviously not part of the Fibbonaci sequence). `-1 + -2 == -3`, after all, and if `first_num` is zero, then you're subtracting 1 on one side and 2 on the other. (Honestly, I don't see how this code is expected to output the Fibbonaci sequence at all).

Comment: Hey Charles, I saw that typo thank you and fixed it. As for the $1 I'm trying to only calculate the fibonacci for the nth term being why its $1 so I only wanted that outcome. Well I would think the total time it takes the function to run and calculate the fib sequence should be a positive number.

Comment: You call `recur_fib $elapsedtime`. Initially, elapsedtime is an empty variable. So you set `first_num` to an empty string. When treated as a number, the empty string is the number 0. Does the problem make sense now?

Comment: I know what you mean Charles but I'm not too sure how to implement changed to fix that I am still trying to at the moment, also want to say I'm fairly new to bash. I really appreaciate you taking time to talk things over I'm sure Ill figure it out. Have a good night!